# Matrix with eigenvalue less than $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real matrix such that:

1. $a_{ii}=0$ for all $i$, $1>a_{ij}\geq0$ for all $i,j$.
2. $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}\in (0,1]$ for all $i$.
3. There is at least a row $i_0$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{i_0j}<1$.

Can we conclude that the maximum eigenvalue of $A$ is less than 1?

By Perron-Frobenius Theorem the maximum eigenvalue is greater or equal than $0$. Note also that, without part 3, one could take a stochastic matrix satisfying 1 and 2, which has always $1$ as an eigenvalue.

**EDIT**: I added the hypothesis $a_{ij}<1$ for all $i,j$. In this case, the example below does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT. The answer is again: no.

Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1/2&1/2&0\\1/2&0&1/2&0\\1/2&1/2&0&0\\a&b&c&0\end{pmatrix}$; for every real $a,b,c$, its spectrum is $\{0,1,-1/2,-1/2\}$.

Comment: The example does not work. By condition 2, the sum of each row cannot be $0$. In your example, the fourth row sums $0$.

Comment: I don't think you understood the meaning of "for every". If you replace $a$, $b$, $c$ with $a = 1, b = 0, c = 0$, you get a counterexample; the same is true for any other triple of $a,b,c$ values *except* when $a+b+c \le 0$.

Comment: @loupblanc I think John Hughes’s comment was meant to be directed at user39756, not at you.  Perhaps you could reread his comment assuming that hypothesis...

Comment: @John Hugues it's m'y fault, I read too fast your post. In fact the OP's comment is about a first version of my post where I chose the last row equal to zero.

Comment: OK -- so we both screwed up a little. Looking forward to reading more of your answers, from which I always learn something. :)

Comment: @John Hugues "we both screwed up a little"; I like this wording. In fact, I do not hate confrontation...

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider for instance

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0\\1/2 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right].$$